# ¿Cual es la diferencia del While y Do While?

Tags: java, while

Queria saber si me pueden dar una definicion basica (soy nuevo en esto por eso pido una explicacion sencilla :/) y no tan compleja del while y do while , en especial del do while tengo mas dudas por que no entiendo que es lo que se va a ejecutar una vez .

Comment: El while realiza  la comparación antes de entrar al ciclo, y el do while lo hace al final del ciclo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**While** y **Do While** son bucles, su contenido "puede" ejecutarse repetidamente, en función de una condición.

Usando la estructura **while** sólo se pasa a ejecutar su contenido si se comprueba una condición lo que puede ocurrir 0, 1 o más veces. **Do While** funciona de forma similar, solo que nos aseguramos de que el contenido sea ejecutado al menos una vez, es decir que aunque su condición no se cumpla, su contenido se ejecuta.

Estas estructuras se presentan de la siguiente forma:

```
// while
while (expression) {
     // statements
}

// do-while
do {
     // statements
} while (expression);
```

donde *expression* es la condición a evaluar para entrar o no a ejecutar el contenido del bucle, cosa que ocurre sí o sí, al menos una vez para el **do while**.

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya pude entender :D , Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente en uno primero se ejecuta la comprobación, mientras que el otro se ejecuta el código dentro de él y despues la comprobación. Un ejemplo sencillo.

```
  public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            boolean x = true;
            int c = 9;
            do{

                c++;
                x = c==10;

            } while (!x );
            System.out.println("do while: "+c);
            // Si suma por lo menos 1
            c = 9;
            x = true;

            while( !x ) {
                c++;
                x = c==10;

            };
            // No entra al ciclo por que primero comprueba. 
            System.out.println("while "+c);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El código del **While** podría no ejecutarse si la condición no se cumple, mientras que con el **Do While** tu código se ejecuta al menos una vez.

A simple vista parecería no ser gran diferencia cuando sabes que siempre se va cumplir tu condición, pero dependiendo de lo que estés programando (y analizando el caso) tendrás que optar por usar **Do While** en lugar de **While**.